# How to install "tree" with command-line?

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo, tree

How do I install "tree" via `apt-get` in Terminal? I have been trying to do `apt-get update tree` but nothing seems to happen.

Is it necessary to include `sudo` in the command?

Comment: `apt-get update` updates the list of available packages. Please read `man apt-get`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use this command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

The command `apt-get update` only updates the package lists. You need `apt-get install` and the package name to install a new package.

And yes, `sudo` is required as you need root privileges in order to install and remove software.

Comment: `apt` is an alias for `apt-get`, so you can use `sudo apt install tree`

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман: You can use that command, but apt is a separate command, it is not an alias, even if it does use `apt-get` which I don't know about.

Comment: Also note that its in the `universe` repo.